# Custom .desktop file -- name doesn't show up in Unity dash on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, unity-dash, .desktop

I have several .desktop files that I migrated over from 12.10 ubuntu. The applications they point to launch just fine, and the image displays in the dash when I search for them...but there isn't any text below the images when they show up in the dash, it's just the image. All other applications that were either installed by default, or installed through the software center show up just fine.

Here's a sample .desktop that I created:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Sublime Text 2
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Awesome Text Editor
Exec=/home/wes/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text
Icon=/home/wes/Sublime Text 2/Icon/128x128/sublime_text.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Here's what I mean:

[image: No text for custom .desktop launcher]

Edit: This is just one example of 2 or 3 .desktop files that I have created in the past, that worked as expected in 12.10, but all seem to be missing the application name in 13.04 (in the dash only). I don't think it is the icon size, as I have tried various different sizes (32x32, 64x64, 128x128, etc...).

Comment: Try to lower picture's size to 64x64 and also include a `Categories=` entry. I assume `Categories=GTK;Development;IDE;` ? Logout-Login to see the changes.

Comment: @NikTh Yes, I have tried all of that, and for whatever reason it just doesn't want to work. Also, it is important to note that this is just one of them...I have 2 or 3 more custom .desktop files that all show up like this in the dash, some have larger icons, some are smaller than 64x64. I'm thinking it's a much more obscure issue.

Comment: What worked for me: I had this problem when the file my .desktop file pointed to wasn't executable.  After `chmod +x` on the application itself (and `sudo update-desktop-database`), it worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem that you did. I messed around with a bunch of settings within my .desktop files to try to get the name to show up in the Unity launcher, since I had created the .desktop files in ~/Desktop then moved them to ~/.local/share/applications

All I had to do to get the Unity application launcher to show the names is log out of Ubuntu and log back in. Pretty lame, I know, but it worked.

At least this shows that in my case (and probably yours too) the .desktop files were not somehow wrong. After all, in my case, the desktop-file-validate program didn't list any errors. There was probably some name cache within Unity that needed to be cleared. It would be more satisfying to know how to do that without logging out, but this workaround is good enough for me for now. Hope this observation helps someone else!

Comment: Yeah, that was my experience as well. I could have sworn that I had relogged during my exploration into this issue and it didn't work. Then one day, after giving up on the issue, the power went out in my house, and on reboot the desktop entries were displaying perfectly fine in Unity.

Comment: Works for me in XFCE also.

Comment: Worked for me in Mint 21 Cinnamon. It is interesting because in Ubuntu I used the `update-desktop-database` successfully without a logout, but not on Mint.

Answer (score 22):

You can validate your `.desktop` files with `desktop-file-validate *.desktop` and then, if there are no errors (it'll tell you what to fix), run `sudo update-desktop-database` to actually update the system's database.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in XFCE.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the validation tip.

Comment: But also take a look at David Jones' answer. It's important that all path point to a exec file

Answer (score 3):

Search in **Dash** for `alacarte` to open **Main Menu**:

[image: alacarte]

In **Main Menu** search for the application that doesn't have name in **Dash**. When you find it, click **Properties** and give it a name (in your case Sublime Text 2 application, in my case Ask Ubuntu web application):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for the input, but this does not answer my question at all. I am well aware there are interfaces to create custom launchers, but my question is "Why does my custom .desktop file not display the application's name?".

Comment: @Wes Because of this. Just search your application in **Main Menu** and you will see that has no name. I experimented the same situation.

Comment: Specifically the issue is an empty value in the `Name` or `Name[your-locale]` line(s). I just encountered this in GNOME, where the Application Finder enables an equivalent editing procedure to above.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu will not register the .desktop file unless whatever you are executing with:

```
Exec=<path-to-executable>
```

is indeed executable, i.e.:

```
chmod a+x <path-to-executable>
```

Comment: Very important answer, `desktop-file-validate` is not validating it!

Answer (score 1):

Corrupted or bad permission desktop file in  `~/.local/share/applications` may overwrite  desktop file in  `/usr/share/applications`.Delete or repair desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` first.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is restarting Cinnamon (if you have Linux Mint) by pressing `ALT+F2` and writing "r". There's surely a similar procedure to restart Unity.

This will refresh the menu cache without logging out and logging back in.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in a fairly straightforward way that probably doesn't apply to most others here--for some reason, my .desktop file included the line `NoDisplay=true`, with a fairly predictable result. After I removed this line and relogged, the app showed up in dash search as hoped.